# Remove column values with NA in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame, called gen, which is represented below

```
     A       B       C       D       E
1    NA      4.35    35.3    3.36    4.87
2    45.2    .463    34.3    NA      34.4
3    NA      34.5    35.6    .457    46.3
```

I would like to remove the **columns** where there are NA's. (I know `na.omit` does it for rows, but I can't seem to find one for columns). The final result would read:

```
     B       C       E
1    4.35    35.3    4.87
2    .463    34.3    34.4
3    34.5    35.6    46.3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
gen <- gen[sapply(gen, function(x) all(!is.na(x)))]
```

Comment: `is.na` is vectorised. You don't have to loop over. It could be done with `df[colSums(is.na(df)) == 0]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
dfrm[ , sapply(dfrm, function(x){ !any(is.na(x)) } )
```

You might want to use instead this variant:

```
dfrm[ , sapply(dfrm, function(x){ all(is.finite(x)) } )
```

If you have Inf or -Inf values in a vector they are not removed or identified with selection based on `is.na`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
gen[colSums(is.na(gen)) == 0]
```